# Unable to install/update apps from Play store on Xiaomi A3 on data plan

Tags: installation, downloading, mobile-network, xiaomi, google-apps

I am trying to download update/install apps from the Play store on my MI A3 Jio connection, but it has been unsuccessful. All services like Facebook, Whatsapp, etc are working fine.
The apps I am trying to download are the following:

- Fancy Text+ Sticker Maker
- Facebook Messenger
- Personal Sticker for whatsapp
- Stickers for whatsapp

But from past one hour, I am not able to download these apps on my Jio  data plan. This problem of not being able to download apps on my Jio connection is a frequent problem. What should I check? Any kind of  data saver is not on.
The OS this phone has is Android 9.
Following screenshot is the situation on my phone.

[image]

Here are settings for app download in playstore you can see that download using any kind of data mobile data plan or wifi both are enabled.
[image]

Wifi at my end was not working so at the time when I posted this question and now when I posted above image a friend came and change the setting of downloading apps on wifi only. So the apps which I could not download on my data plan could be downloaded on Wi-Fi connection.

I am not sure if it was a problem from mobile network service provider end or it is a problem in my phone or some thing which I don't know.

Comment: Are you trying to download them from the Play Store? Are you able to install any other app but them alone?

Comment: Yes I am trying to download them from.playstore. previously I have installed whatsapp etc from playstore.

Comment: See if after restarting the device you are able to download from the Play Store.

Comment: I had restarted phone before posting the question here and any other app also I am not able to download from playstore.

Comment: I am having this problem in Data Plan i.e. when I am using Data Plan then I can not download apps. But when I am able to connect to a wifi  then apps can be downloaded and installed via google play store.

Comment: For some reason, there's also [a very recent & similar question regarding blocked Google services on mobile data](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/217993). That said, Jio seems to [block access to some websites](https://www.bgr.in/news/reliance-jio-may-be-blocking-proxy-and-vpn-websites-and-violating-net-neutrality-report/), and there's a big possibility that this is also caused by a misconfiguration on their side. In that case, try VPN if it helps (though it's also known that Jio also blocking VPN), or contact them directly about this issue.

Comment: Yes now I am able to understand in a market competition to eliminate other company reliance jio is blocking every thing google telegram etc etc .